# similar to STGeomFromText function

Tags: sql-server, geospatial, arcgis

In ArcGis geological point represent in mssql database as hexa values 
eg : `0x**7214**0000010C00000000004C0D4100000000004C0D41`

I used mssql geospatial function as below

```
$query1="DECLARE @Point GEOMETRY
SET @Point = geometry::STGeomFromText('POINT (240000 240000)',0)   INSERT INTO main (id, mname, pdata) VALUES (1,'update_1',@Point)";
```

but it retuns hexa values as `0x**0000**0000010C00000000004C0D4100000000004C0D41`

first 4 characters are different from the required outcome , is there any otherway to get that ? I dont have much idea about geospatial function. String replace is not possible thanks.

I am expecting `0x72140000010C00000000004C0D4100000000004C0D41`

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're using SRID 5234, which is for Sri Lanka? In your `STGeomFromText` you have 0 as the second parameter, which is the SRID. Set that to 5234 and you will get the correct output.

Comment: 100% correct. .exactly that was the missing  parameter. Thanks a lot